# pulling in another column to query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that I need to pull an additional column into. I am having a moment of dead grey matter and need help.

query as is

```
SELECT g.groupId,g.name AS groupName,l.logId,l.name AS logName, i.itemID,
i.name AS itemName, le.userName,completed, i.optimalMin,i.optimalMax ,le.value,
u.name AS unitDescription,g.parentId
FROM logExceptions le
INNER JOIN logs l ON l.logID = le.logID
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
INNER JOIN items i ON le.itemId = i.itemId
INNER JOIN units u ON i.unitId = u.unitId
```

The column name is actually l.name but for the parentId. Attached images will show what I mean.

Comment: You're already pulling a field called `l.name`. You haven't posted your images.

Comment: Maybe you should have waited for your brain to resurrect itself before composing this question...

Comment: SOLUTION

    SELECT g.groupId,g.name AS groupName,l.logId,l.name AS logName, i.itemID,
    i.name AS itemName, le.userName,completed, i.optimalMin,i.optimalMax ,le.value,
    u.name AS unitDescription,g.parentId,g1.name AS parentName
    FROM logExceptions le
    INNER JOIN logs l ON l.logID = le.logID
    INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
    INNER JOIN items i ON le.itemId = i.itemId
    left JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId
    INNER JOIN units u ON i.unitId = u.unitId

Comment: @Mike just started using this site - can't post images

Comment: @Bohemian - maybe so but what fun would that be!

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question. Copy-paste your "answer" comment as a proper answer and accept it (you'll find a hollow tick mark you can click). Others with the same problem can then find your solution more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION** SELECT g.groupId,g.name AS groupName,l.logId,l.name AS logName, i.itemID, i.name AS itemName, le.userName,completed, i.optimalMin,i.optimalMax ,le.value, u.name AS unitDescription,g.parentId,g1.name AS parentName FROM logExceptions le INNER JOIN logs l ON l.logID = le.logID INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId INNER JOIN items i ON le.itemId = i.itemId left JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId INNER JOIN units u ON i.unitId = u.unitId